# Python index out of range work-around

Tags: python, for-loop

I am a beginner in coding.  I am searching for a solution to this problem:
I am supposed to write a function that well take a string of text with words AND numbers, separated with spaces, and from that string output True if there are 3 words in a row.

example:

```
'123 a b c' == True  
'a 123 b c' == False
```

What I have tried:

```
def 3_in_a_row(words):
    words = words.split(" ")
    for i in range(len(words)):
         return words[i].isalpha() and words[i+1].isalpha() and words[i+2].isalpha()
```

If I try this I get a `list index out of range` error because when I near the end of the list, there are not 2 words after `i` to check.

What is the best way to limit this function so that it will stop when there are not 2 items after `i` to check?  What is a better way to do this?

Comment: Thank you very much.  I understand where I went wrong now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can limit the range:

```
range(len(words) - 2)
```

so it won't produce indices that you cannot add 2 to.

Your loop is returning too early, however. You are returning the result of testing the *first 3 words only*. Your test will fail for `'123 a b c'`, for example, because only `'123', 'a', 'b'` is tested in the first iteration. Alter your loop to:

```
def three_in_a_row(words):
    words = words.split(" ")
    for i in range(len(words) - 2):
         if words[i].isalpha() and words[i+1].isalpha() and words[i+2].isalpha():
             return True
    return False
```

This now will return early if you found three words in a row, and only after scanning *all words* will it declare defeat and return `False`.

Some other tips:

- You cannot start a Python identifier (like a function name) with a digit. The first character *has* to be a letter. I renamed your function above to `three_in_a_row()`.
- Use `words.split()` without an argument. That splits on *arbitrary whitespace* and ignores whitespace at the start and end. This means the split will work even if there are accidentally 2 spaces in between somewhere, or a newline at the end or a tab character.
- You can use the [`all()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to test things in a loop:

  ```
  if all(w.isalpha() for w in words[i:i + 3]):
  ```

  is a more compact way of spelling the same test.

Demo with those updates:

```
>>> def three_in_a_row(words):
...     words = words.split()
...     for i in range(len(words) - 2):
...         if all(w.isalpha() for w in words[i:i + 3]):
...              return True
...     return False
... 
>>> three_in_a_row('123 a b c')
True
>>> three_in_a_row('a 123 b c')
False
>>> three_in_a_row('a  b c 123')
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding [@martijn's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28513609/793428) detailed answer on the usage of `all`, here is the one-line alternative;

```
>>> l = '.. a b .. e f .. g h i'.split()
>>> pairs = [l[i:i + 3] for i in xrange(len(l))] 

>>> result = any([all(c.isalpha() for c in pair) for pair in pairs if len(pair) == 3])
```